# trying to covert pinescript v2 to v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v2

hello im trying covert to v5 but having a problem understanding these parts of code

```
// Setup trading conditions based on last performed trades performance.
direction = na(direction[1]) ? 1 : crossunder(fast_ma, slow_ma) and direction[1] > 0 ? -1 : crossover(fast_ma, slow_ma) and direction[1] < 0 ? 1 : direction[1]

buy_cond = direction > 0 and strategy.opentrades < 1
sel_cond = direction < 0 and strategy.opentrades < 1

f_martingale_wins_multiplier(_multiplier) => _return = na(_return[1]) ? 1 : change(strategy.losstrades) > 0 ? 1 : change(strategy.wintrades) > 0 or change(strategy.eventrades) > 0 ? _return[1] * _multiplier : _return[1]
f_martingale_loss_multiplier(_multiplier) => _return = na(_return[1]) ? 1 : change(strategy.wintrades) > 0 ? 1 : change(strategy.losstrades) > 0 or change(strategy.eventrades) > 0 ? _return[1] * _multiplier : _return[1]

mode = change(strategy.wintrades) > 0 ? 1 : change(strategy.losstrades) > 0 ? -1 : nz(mode[1], 1)
trade_multiplier = mode > 0 ? f_martingale_wins_multiplier(wins_multiplier) : f_martingale_loss_multiplier(losses_multiplier)
```

full code

```
//@version=2
strategy(title='[RS]Function Martingale Multiplier - MA Crossover Bias V1', overlay=false, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, default_qty_value=1000, initial_capital=100000, currency=currency.USD)
wins_multiplier = input(defval=1.00, title='Scaling Multiplier for Consecutive Wins:')
losses_multiplier = input(defval=2.00, title='Scaling Multiplier for Consecutive Losses:')
src = input(close)
fast_ma = ema(src, input(5))
slow_ma = ema(src, input(55))
// Setup trading conditions based on last performed trades performance.
direction = na(direction[1]) ? 1 : crossunder(fast_ma, slow_ma) and direction[1] > 0 ? -1 : crossover(fast_ma, slow_ma) and direction[1] < 0 ? 1 : direction[1]

buy_cond = direction > 0 and strategy.opentrades < 1
sel_cond = direction < 0 and strategy.opentrades < 1

f_martingale_wins_multiplier(_multiplier) => _return = na(_return[1]) ? 1 : change(strategy.losstrades) > 0 ? 1 : change(strategy.wintrades) > 0 or change(strategy.eventrades) > 0 ? _return[1] * _multiplier : _return[1]
f_martingale_loss_multiplier(_multiplier) => _return = na(_return[1]) ? 1 : change(strategy.wintrades) > 0 ? 1 : change(strategy.losstrades) > 0 or change(strategy.eventrades) > 0 ? _return[1] * _multiplier : _return[1]

mode = change(strategy.wintrades) > 0 ? 1 : change(strategy.losstrades) > 0 ? -1 : nz(mode[1], 1)
trade_multiplier = mode > 0 ? f_martingale_wins_multiplier(wins_multiplier) : f_martingale_loss_multiplier(losses_multiplier)

trade_size = input(defval=100, title='Base trade value:')
trade_size_multiplied = trade_size * trade_multiplier

strategy.entry('B', long=true, qty=trade_size_multiplied, when=buy_cond)
strategy.entry('S', long=false, qty=trade_size_multiplied, when=sel_cond)

take_profit = input(defval=250, title='TP in ticks(1/10 of a pip):')
stop_loss = input(defval=100, title='SL in ticks(1/10 of a pip):')
strategy.exit('B', from_entry='B', profit=take_profit, loss=stop_loss)
strategy.exit('S', from_entry='S', profit=take_profit, loss=stop_loss)

plot(series=strategy.equity, title='Equity', color=black, linewidth=2)
plot(series=lowest(strategy.equity, 100), title='Base', color=red)
```

Comment: here is the instruction to convert it to pine v3
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed
after converting script to v3 use autoconverter to pine v4, then to v5 in the menu